# Dealing with linkedlist in c

Tags: c, linked-list

i've a header declared like this

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Nodo {
    struct Nodo *pAnterior;
    struct Nodo *pProximo;
    CACHORRO cachorro;
};

typedef struct Nodo *Lista;
typedef struct Nodo *DoenteMachucado;
typedef struct Nodo *portePequeno;
typedef struct Nodo *porteMedio;
typedef struct Nodo *porteGrande;
```

But when i try to use the function

```
void inserir(Lista *lista, CACHORRO elem)
{
    Lista Nodo;
    Nodo = (Lista)malloc(sizeof(struct Nodo));
    if(Nodo == NULL)
        printf("Sem memoria\n");

    Nodo->cachorro = elem;
    Nodo->pAnterior = NULL;
    Nodo->pProximo = (*lista);

    if((*lista) != NULL)
        (*lista)->pAnterior = Nodo;

    (*lista) = Nodo;
}
```

like this

```
inserir(DoenteMachucado, elem);
```

it doesnt work, i am declaring a elem CACHORRO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  void inserir(Lista *lista, CACHORRO elem)
```

The above statement reduces to

```
  void inserir(struct Nodo **lista, CACHORRO elem)//1
```

and you call the above function as

```
  DoenteMachucado something; 
  inserir(something, elem); //remember DoenteMachucado is a type not a variable ,something is a variable.so i have changed this.
```

where the first argument is of type `struct Nodo*`

```
  inserir(struct Nodo* something, elem);//2
```

the parameters don't match at 1 and 2.
you might want to call the function as

```
 DoenteMachucado something;
 inserir(&something, elem);
```